# R: ggbiplot - why can't I control the number of legend columns with guide_legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties, ggbiplot

I use `ggbiplot` regularly and can control every aspect of the plot produced using `ggplot2` tools, since it inherits from `ggplot2`...

In `ggplot2`, I usually control the number of columns in the legend with a line of the form:

```
ggplot2::guides(fill=ggplot2::guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

However, this does not seem to work in `ggbiplot` (while everything else `ggplot2`-related does work).

Please check the MWE below with `iris` data, the only thing I want to do here is specify 2 columns for the legend (for illustration purposes, I know there are only 3 Species levels, but this was the example I had more at hand).

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(iris)
pca.obj <- prcomp(iris[,1:4], center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE)
P <- ggbiplot(pca.obj,
              obs.scale = 1,
              var.scale=1,
              ellipse=T,
              circle=F,
              varname.size=3,
              var.axes=T,
              groups=iris$Species, #no need for coloring, I'm making the points invisible
              alpha=0) + #invisible points, I add them below
ggplot2::theme_light() +
ggplot2::scale_color_manual("spec", values=c("red","black","pink"), guide=ggplot2::guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=19, size=5, linetype=0))) +
ggplot2::guides(fill=ggplot2::guide_legend(ncol=2)) #THIS DOES NOT WORK HERE, WHY?
P$layers <- c(geom_point(aes(color=iris$Species), cex=3), P$layers) #add geom_point in a layer underneath (only way I have to change the size of the points in ggbiplot)
png(filename="test.png", height=600, width=600)
print(#or ggsave()
  P
)
dev.off()
```

This produces the following biplot:

[image: test]

See how the number of columns in the legend never changes... Is there a way to specify the number of legend columns in `ggbiplot`? Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but it seems like you map **color** to 'Species' (`groups=iris$Species`, `scale_color_manual`), but then you try to edit a **fill** scale (`guides(fill=`). Can you try `guides(color=`?

Comment: that's just pretty much to prove that I can modify other aspects in the legend with `ggplot2` tools, that part works. I don't care about the coloring, it's just the legend `ncol` that doesn't work...

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you _don't have a fill legend_ - you have a _color_ legend - but when you try to modify `ncol`, you refer to a (non-existing) _fill_ legend (`guides(fill=`).

Comment: Also, the `alpha=0` + `P$layers <- c(geom_point(aes(color=iris$Species), cex=3), P$layers)` may be replaced by `geom_point(aes(color = iris$Species), size = 3)`

Comment: Should I add a `scale_fill_manual` entry then? As for your second point, I really need to play with layers like that when doing these biplots, otherwise the points are drawn on top of the vector arrows masking them completely if there are many points

Comment: To reiterate my first comment: you map point _color_ to 'Species' (`groups=iris$Species`; "`groups`: If provided the points will be _colored_ according to `groups`"). Thus, you get a _color_ legend. If you want to make changes to the _color_  legend in `guides`, use `guides(**color** =`, i.e. `guides(color = guide_legend(ncol = 2))` (_not_ `guides(fill = `). No, don't add `scale_fill_manual`. Again, you have a _color_ scale, and you create your own color scale with `scale_color_manual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be simpler to include the `ncol = 2` in the first call to `guide_legend()`. I.e.

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(iris)
pca.obj <- prcomp(iris[,1:4], center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE)
P <- ggbiplot(pca.obj,
              obs.scale = 1,
              var.scale=1,
              ellipse=T,
              circle=F,
              varname.size=3,
              var.axes=T,
              groups=iris$Species, #no need for coloring, I'm making the points invisible
              alpha=0) + #invisible points, I add them below
ggplot2::theme_light() +
ggplot2::scale_color_manual("spec", values=c("red","black","pink"), guide=ggplot2::guide_legend(ncol = 2, override.aes=list(shape=19, size=5, linetype=0))) # +
# ggplot2::guides(fill=ggplot2::guide_legend(ncol=2)) #THIS DOES NOT WORK HERE, WHY?
P$layers <- c(geom_point(aes(color=iris$Species), cex=3), P$layers) #add geom_point in a layer underneath (only way I have to change the size of the points in ggbiplot)
png(filename="test.png", height=600, width=600)
print(#or ggsave()
  P
)
dev.off()
```

[image]

As Henrik says, it's down to a mismatch between `fill =`  and `color =` .

Comment: yes this is it! I thought I had tried it before, but I guess I probably included `ncol` inside the `override.aes=list()`